# Calling Windows API from assembly but there is no hardcoded address

Tags: windows, assembly, fasm

I am learning fasm on windows XP environment
while I read a fasm source code, I found invoke macro:

```
invoke  MessageBox,0,[_strbuf],_msgcap,MB_ICONINFORMATION+MB_OK
```

and import macro.

```
import user,\
     MessageBox,'MessageBoxA',\
     wsprintf,'wsprintfA'
```

but I couldn't find any hard-coded address of `MessageBoxA` nor loading user32.dll in the assembly code.
There are only macro definitions which label the string but not an address.

My assumption is this:

1. there is code that load user32.dll and return start address of loaded dll => here, let us call the returned address to location A
2. there are pairs for hard-coded address and label (e.g. `MessageBoxA` = 0x00000000)
3. so the instruction 'call' can call `MessageBoxA` label(which will be converted to location A + `MessageBoxA` offset)

Is my assumption wrong?
I wonder how APIs are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the FASM documentation](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32), it explains how `MessageBoxA()` is referenced in user32.dll.

Then [read the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx) about how Windows executables actually work. Pay particular attention to the section about PE File Imports, which explains how the address of imported DLL functions are resolved at run-time.

In a nutshell, the `import` statement in FASM is setting up an entry in a lookup table within the compiled EXE file.  The OS then fills in that lookup table when the EXE is loaded into memory before its code begins running.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screen shot from the free Dependency Walker tool.

Note: there is a function name, Ordinal and Entry Point.

So yes, what you inferred is pretty much it.  The functions are linked at runtime instead of at compile time.  (DLL Dynamic **Link** Library).

[image]